# Animate a button background color on error

Tags: wpf, animation

To indicate an error, I'd like to temporarily change the background color of a button. I'm new to WPF animations and couldn't find a simple example to proceed from. And to further complicate matters, I'm using a Trigger to deal with error notification.

So here's my XAML, and I'd like to know how to replace the Background Setter with an animation (say, blink red three times in five seconds or something like that).

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="Button">
      <!--Clear the default error template (a red border)-->
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
          <!--TODO: Replace with animation-->
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding ProgramCommand, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
        Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}">
      _Program
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm also open to suggestions of better (simple) error notification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Trigger.EnterActions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase.enteractions.aspx) for that.

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                From="White" To="Red" RepeatBehavior="3x" AutoReverse="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

(*Assumes the background to be a `SolidColorBrush`, since the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` points to its `Color` property*)

---

For gradients you can animate a specific stop's color as well, e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestInt}">
    <TextBox.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" Duration="0:0:0.3"
                                                From="White" To="Red" RepeatBehavior="3x" AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Good clarification, but same problem as @novacara's code - it won't work if I don't specify the `Storyboard.Target`, and I don't know how to do that correctly inside of a `Style`

Comment: What target? You should not need any or what background do you want to animate?

Comment: The `ColorAnimation`'s attached `Storyboard.Target`. I don't get it, because the ToolTip setter in my code works fine binding to Self, but this animation doesn't. And it just plain doesn't work if I don't specify a Target.

Comment: Here's the binding error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'object' ''LinearGradientBrush' (HashCode=24852100)'. null

Maybe it's because I'm binding to a Button?

Comment: Check my second example. Or explicitly overwrite the default Background (which is a complex gradient) of the button with a SolidColorBrush.

Comment: Would it make a difference at all if TargetProperty was Button.Background?

Comment: Oh, that works better. Now it's animating about the top third of the button. Thanks for clarifying - I thought the second example would be if I wanted a Gradient; I didn't think about the Button having a gradient by default.

Comment: Yes, it would look for a property called `Button` in the button, which does not exist, unless you only use it for "decoration", e.g. `(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)` is equivalent to `Background.Color`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @H.B.'s answer, here's my final code. You'll notice that, instead of setting the Button's Background to a SolidColor, I kludged in a color change at each gradient of the default button brush. This creates an effect that turns the entire button red, but allows it to revert back to its normal gradient look.

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="Button">
      <!--Clear the default error template (a red border)-->
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="ToolTip"
              Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
          <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[2].Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[3].Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding ProgramCommand, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
        Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}">
      _Program
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
   <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
         <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" From="White" 
            To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="3x"/>
      </Storyboard>
   </BeginStoryboard>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: I've almost got it, but it seems that I need to specify `Storyboard.Target` or else the target is a LinearGradientBrush. I would set it to RelativeResource TemplatedParent, but there is no template on this control (i.e. if I include a Background.Color setter, TemplatedParent works; if I don't, it doesn't). And I can't use `Storyboard.TargetName` in a Style (according to the compiler).